# can't get data out of array

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do a get request.  this is my code which is almost an exact copy from the jquery website.  I am using firebug and adding a breakmark at alert.  At that line, data is an object with atribute id.  But my alert box says undefined.  Where am I losing the value of data.id?

```
$( "span" ).click(function() {
$.get("jasonBands.jsp", { bandId:$(this).attr("id") },
function(data){
alert("Data Loaded: " + data.id);
console.log(data);
},"json");

$( "#band-summary-dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

Console log:

```
bandBio
    "Great band from new jersey"


bandName
"Patrick Dyer Wolf"


id
"agtteXZlbnVlbWVudXIKCxIEQmFuZBh6DA"


image
"/images/basicProfile.jpg"


url
"band.jsp?bandId=agtteXZlbnVlbWVudXIKCxIEQmFuZBh6DA"
```

Comment: can you add output from `console.log(data);` or exact copy of `data` object content from debugger?

Comment: Does jasonBands.jsp return an ID anyway?

Comment: Can u see in firebug's Net tab what data u get from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my response object.  I was sending  `[{"id":"cnauioweno"}]` it wanted `{"id":"cnauioweno"}`

Answer (score 0):

Script looks good, you'll probably have some typo (is `id` really `id`, not an `Id`?) or different data structure is coming back from webservice (like array, array of objects) instead of what you expect.